# Property "StrongAuthenticationUserDetails" cannot be found in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, office365

Recently I created a script to see who had completed their SSPR authentications. Users can setup mobile verifications and email verification. They need at least 2 methods to be completed, so I need to know if they filled in their mobile methods but also their mobile methods.

Its not hard to create, but the only issue I have is that for some reason the Property "StrongAuthenticationUserDetails" not could be found.

I use the following command:

```
get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName "EMAILADRESS" | select -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationUserDetails
```

Another property like StrongAuthenticationMethods does work well. Last time I created this script, the StrongAuthenticationUserDetails also worked, but for some reason not anymore.

Am I doing something wrong?

Already seach the internet, updated my azure module but none of it works or gives me the needed information.

Comment: You have a `$` at the beginning of your command. Is that a typo in this post only?

Comment: Yep, typo. Sorry :)

Comment: Have you checked `| Get-Member Strong*` ?

Comment: If the attribute has no data, then your command should return nothing. Otherwise, it should have a Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails object as data. Does the command return something other than those two?

Comment: If I use ```| Get-Member Strong*``` its only saying StrongAuthenticationMethods, StrongAuthenticationRequirements and StrongPasswordRequired.

Comment: @AdminOfThings
I don't know if I understand correctly, but when I run the command, it says **"Property "StrongAuthenticationUserDetails" cannot be found"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed it myself. Apparently the issue was in the version I used for MsOnline. Couldnt upgrade either. So I deleted the whole MSOnline module in the powershell folder and installed it again with `install-module MSOnline -force`

Problem is now fixed.